# Error in `roc_auc()`: ! Can't rename variables in this context. Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred

Tags: r, rlang

When I make machine learning model of classification such as decision tree, randomforest like that,
I face the error

```
# ROC curve
final_pred %>%
  roc_curve(truth = Personal_Loan, 
            estimate = .pred_Yes) %>%
  autoplot()
```

> **Error in `roc_curve()`:**
> ! Can't rename variables in this context.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

```
# lift curve
final_pred %>%
  lift_curve(truth = Personal_Loan, 
             estimate = .pred_Yes) %>%
  autoplot()
```

> **Error in `lift_curve()`:**
> ! Can't rename variables in this context.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

```
# gain curve
final_pred %>%
  gain_curve(truth = Personal_Loan, 
             estimate = .pred_Yes) %>%
  autoplot()
```

> **Error in `gain_curve()`:**
> ! Can't rename variables in this context.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

update packages ( yardstick package)

Comment: Did you follow the suggestion from the error message and run `rlang::last_trace()`? Could you add the output of this comment to your question?

Comment: The error probably comes from you naming the argument `.pred_Yes`. This argument does not exist in the `yardstick::roc_curve` function. It expects unquoted column names. So provided the column `.pred_Yes` exists in `final_pred`, try to run `roc_curve(truth = Personal_Loan, .pred_Yes)`.